# vs web site compiler options

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

Okay, I shot myself in the foot somewhere. I've got a VB web site that was compiling successfully. Now, I don't know what I changed, but I get errors saying that I've failed to give an "as" clause on my variable declarations. Like I used to have option infer on but now it's off.

In my web.config it says compilation strict="false" explicit="true", but there doesn't appear to be an option for "infer".

I don't see any screen where I can change this. MSDN docs say to go to the project property page and the "compile" tab. But there is no compile tab. There's a "build" tab but there's nothing about strict, explicit, etc there.

Where do I set this?

Comment: Sharing the exact error message may help more.

Comment: Make sure it is really (or still) a VB project.  VB has a Compile Page/Tab but  C# has a Build page/tab (and lacks Option Strict, Option Explicit options)

Comment: The exact error message is: "Variable declaration without an As; type Object assumed". I'm also getting messages like "'row' is not declared" when I relied on am implicit definition in a loop, "for row in ..."

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
<compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb"
          type="Microsoft.VisualBasic.VBCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
          warningLevel="4">
    <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v3.5"/>
    <providerOption name="OptionInfer" value="true"/>
    <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false"/>
</compiler>
```